# FullCalendar Header Buttons Invisible

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Starting with the FullCalendar plugin, decided to tweak the header:

```
  var calendar = $('#calendar');

  calendar.fullCalendar({
    buttonIcons : {
      prev: 'left-single-arrow',
      next: 'right-single-arrow'
    },
    header: {
      left: 'prev',
      center: "title",
      right: 'prev, next'
    }

  });
```

The title shows up fine, but left & right have show up as having 0px x 0px.

```
div.fc-left 0px x 0px
```

I have the CSS file included, the calender itself is drawing:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/fullcalendar.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

What am I doing wrong?